# Will contents of the List view auto refresh, if I bind the cursor using a customized SimpleCursorAdaptor?

Tags: android

I have a List view bound to a cursor. My database will be updated by a separate thread. I'm not getting the list control with the new items. Any help with sample code...
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After modifying the data set that is connected on the adapter you must call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) to notify the adapter to update the views with the new data. You must also call [requery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#requery%28%29) on the Cursor to update the cursor with new data. To clarify you should call requery before notifyDataSetChanged.